# In Swift, how to set default date entry to today

Tags: swift, datepicker, simpledateformat

I want a user to enter a start date in a text field.

How do I set the default date of the text field to today's date?

Simples?

Answer (score 0):

In your **viewDidLoad()** try this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle   
yourTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Refer to the Apple docs to learn more about [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/)

Comment: testLabel.text = NSDateFormatter().stringFromDate(NSDate())

Comment: Instantiate dateFormatter and set it as you like at first, and then update your label. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   

    let todaysDate = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: todaysDate)

    yourTextField.text = dateString
}
```